# Using javascript (coffeescript/rails) to submit 2 different forms, the second depending on the information saved in the first

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a form where the user is filling out information including an email address and company information. The user then has the option just to save the information. Or click another button which sends off an email to the company that they just entered.

To solve this I have 2 forms. The first containing all of the company information. The second is a hidden form that posts the the email request controller.

I hide the second form so the user only sees the first, and I place a button that is not hidden which is used to send the email.

The button triggers the following coffeescript:

```
$('#send_email_request').click( ->
    $('#send_email_request').off('click');
    $('#send_email_request').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.save_reference').submit();
    $('.request_information_email_form').submit();
)
```

The issue is request_information_email_form is for some reason being executed before the save_reference_form.  I need the save_reference form to run first so that I have access to the email address and company information in my request_information_email controller.

Am i going about this incorrectly?

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: do you really need a hidden form, can you not simply change the action  (url) of the visible form tag and maybe the value of a hidden tag to let yourself know what was clicked and submit that?

Comment: if you think another button will always will do save the reference and send mail, then do it in server side, first save all your reference and send a mail, instead of triggering from client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem, the user does not need to be able to enter any data into the second form.

You could just use one form with two submit buttons, giving the button which requests emailed information a name-attribute. Then in the `new`-action of the controller check for `params[:name].nil?` and redirect to the other controller or call the respective functions.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form like this implies that the browser current window is going to do an HTTP POST request. This means that the window will be redirected to the URL address written in the the form's action property. As a browser's window cannot be in two addresses at the same time, you cannot submit the two forms the way you are trying to do.

Instead, you should first "serialize" the contents of each form and then do two separate AJAX requests. The serialized data should be placed as POST parameters in each request.

Please refer to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for more information on how to serialize a form and how to do an AJAX request.

Comment: You can use the Rails UJS stuff + jQuery rails to fire off the two requests without much effort... take a look at the docs for the jquery ujs stuff: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery